# How do I fix the nav bar after edits and now mobile version doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I decided to try a new piece of code from this URL:

https://webdevtrick.com/css-responsive-navbar/

The code works by itself, but I wanted to have my own navbar with more links and different texts. The code works on larger screens perfectly, but once you switch to a mobile screen size, or adjust the screen in general, the hamburger menu doesn't even activate and there is sometimes white space in the nav bar as you adjust the screen. I'm wondering how I can fix this so it works again but with my code. I only changed the html file.

Here is my HTML code, the only thing I changed.

view-source:https://366d8314c44a4a0297f3ee9cdf35ce14.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_static/ItalianHonors/italian3.html#

and here is the original HTML code.

view-source:https://366d8314c44a4a0297f3ee9cdf35ce14.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_static/ItalianTest/index.html#

I am pretty new to coding, so any help is appreciated since this is for a future project of mine. I am pretty sure that with the new html code, new css rules need to be defined, but I just don't know what.

also here is a preview of the faulty code:

view-source:https://366d8314c44a4a0297f3ee9cdf35ce14.vfs.cloud9.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/_static/ItalianHonors/italian3.html#!

Comment: "Oops VFS connection does not exist"

Comment: It would be best if you post your scripts here rather then using a link redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If you code you have some CSS like `Bootstrap`, `BULMA` or other `CSS Framework`. Maybe I can say that your `CSS collides` with the `NAVBAR` that you want to include in your `HTML`

**Or maybe** with your explanation, there is a problem with your Javascript. I can't guess what your problem is. Because you are very minimal in providing examples and some code.

Because after I tried code from https://webdevtrick.com/css-responsive-navbar/ 
I didn't experience any problem.

**Like the example below.**

```js
/** code by webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com ) **/
(function($) { 
  $(function() { 
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }); 
})(jQuery);
```

```css
 /** code by webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com ) **/
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    font-family: 'Righteous', cursive;
}
.nav-bar {
  height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
.brand a img {
    max-height: 70px;
}
.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #262626;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: #2ab1ce;
  color: #ffffff;
}
nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}
nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 798px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }

  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 25%;
     
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }

  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
    .brand a img {
        max-height: 60px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 799px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive Dropdown nav-bar Bar</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
 
<body>
 
  <section class="nav-bar">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="brand">
      <a href="https://webdevtrick.com/"><img src="https://webdevtrick.com/wp-content/uploads/logo-fb-1.png"></a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Web Design</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Web Development</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Graphic Design</a>
        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Photoshop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Illustrator</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">InDesign</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">SEO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
 
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="function.js"></script>
</body>
 
</html>
```